# JavaScript passing arguments to button onclick functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I'm trying to create a bunch of buttons via loop, and use the loop iterator as an argument for each of the button onclick functions.

My code:

```
var testFnc = function(i) { alert("Arg: " + i); }

mainDiv.append(create_button(name, "buttonCSS", testFnc(i)));
```

However the functions are called automatically as the page loads and the buttons are placed (i.e. I see the alerts right away).

I'm sure there's some common design pattern for this.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass extra parameter to jQuery getJSON() success callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129145/pass-extra-parameter-to-jquery-getjson-success-callback-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to, for each button, call a "[self-executing](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)" function that creates a separate function.

```
mainDiv.append(create_button(name, "buttonCSS", (function(i) {

    // For the function below, i comes from
    // this function's scope, not the outside scope.

    return function() {
        testFnc(i);
    };

})(i) ));
```

This will allow you to change the value of `i` outside the function and leave existing buttons unaffected.

(If you are creating a lot of buttons (perhaps thousands), it might be better to change the `create_button` function to add a property to the button element itself and have your function check that. Or if your code does not need to work in Internet Explorer 8 or below, you can use the [`bind()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) instead of the above code.)

Comment: Thank you. And this can be extended easily to multiple arguments, right?

Comment: @YoungMoney: Yes, just add the additional parameters. In the above code, you would need to replace all three occurrences of `(i)` with `(i, j)` to add a new parameter `j`.

Answer (score 2):

Note: for a very detailed explanation of this, please see my [previous answer to an identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129145/pass-extra-parameter-to-jquery-getjson-success-callback-function/6129271#6129271).

1. By using parentheses, you're *calling* testFnc and passing its return value to the `create_button` function, so of course it alerts right away. Instead, you need to pass in an actual function object without invoking it. Do this by wrapping `testFnc` in an anonymous function, ala `function() { testFunc(i); }`. Can you see how this returns a function that will be run later rather than immediately?
2. This by itself still won't work, since `i` participates in a *closure*  around it, so that when the click event runs it uses *the most recent value* of i (the value it was at the end of the loop), rather than the one at the time of binding. To fix this, create a new closure around a different variable—positioned only in the immediate scope of your callback and no higher—that will be given the *value* of `i` so that the click event has the value as of the time of binding, not the time of execution of the bound function.

   Here's how to do this:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      mainDiv.append(
         create_button(name, "buttonCSS", (function(val) {
            return function() {
               testFnc(val);
            };
         }(i)))
      );
   }
   ```

   I'm sure that looks a bit confusing, but the point is that wrapping the function that is called (the one that is returned) in another function creates a new scope with a variable `val` that isn't used in any outer function. This makes the closure only over the immediate value, detaching it from `i`, which is what you want. There is a deeper explanation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129145/pass-extra-parameter-to-jquery-getjson-success-callback-function/6129271#6129271).

Please note that one other answer on this page reuses `i` which could be confusing. That will work, but then it is unclear inside of the inner function which `i` is being referred to! I think it is better practice to avoid any confusion by using a different variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery?  You could reference the class of a button

```
<button class='my-custom-class' data-index='0'>This button</button>
```

and in `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
  buildButtons();

  $('.my-custom-class').on('click', function () { 
    var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
    alert('Arg: ' + index);
  });
});
```

I suggest using a custom `data-*` attribute since you can use the `attr` property in jQuery to access the custom attribute.  This is one way you could implement it.